# Redirecting user upon login

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, session

I am trying to display different header based on user login. User is able to login using login.php. However, I am not able to display the header.php when the user is not logged in or logged in. I would want the page to display profile form content when he is logged in and vice versa. Can anyone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <?php
        require("header.php");
        ?>
        <div class = "container">
        //form content
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

## config.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpassword = "123";
$dbdatabase = "db";
$db = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("couldn't connect to the Database");
mysqli_select_db($db, $dbdatabase) or die ("couldn't find db");
?>
```

## header.php

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN']) == TRUE) {
    session_unset();
    session_regenerate_id();
}
include("config.php");
?>
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <?php
    //if user is logged in, display navigation bar with user data
    if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN']) == TRUE){ ?>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                //navigation - profile form content
            </nav>     
    <?php}
    //if user is not logged in, ask them to login
    else { ?>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                //user log in here
                //navigation - login form content
            </nav>

    <?php } ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

## login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("config.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN'])) {
header("Location: index.php");
die();
}


$useremail = $_POST['Lemail'];
$userpassword =  $_POST['Lpass'];

if ($useremail&&$userpassword) {

    $sql = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userEmail='$useremail' and userpassword = $userpassword" );
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    if ($numrows!=0) {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            $_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN'] = 1;
            $dbemail = $row['email'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
            $dbname = $row['firs_Name'];
        }
        if ($useremail==$dbemail&&$userpassword==$dbpassword) {
              header("Location: index.php");
            $_SESSION['Lemail']= $useremail;
            die();

        }
        else
             header("Location: index.php");
            die();
    }
    else
        die("That user doesn't exist!");
}
else
    die("please enter username and password");
```

?>

Comment: Why are you calling `session_unset()` when the user is logged in?

Comment: You're missing the `<` at the beginning of `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: `mysql_fetcxh_assoc` should be `mysql_fetch_assoc`. Also be sure to include `die()` or `exit()` calls after you redirect to prevent further execution. Finally, You only call `session_start()` once when a script starts, not for every variable you want to set.

Comment: sorry, im kind of new to php but is it not necessary to allocate if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN']) == TRUE) {
    session_unset();
    session_regenerate_id();
} ?

Comment: You should always have an `exit;` after a `header('location: ...');`. `session_start()` takes session options, not your session keys so you don't need all those `session_start()` (and the options wasn't introduced until PHP 7). When you have started sessions (with `session_start()` in the top of the file), the `$_SESSION` variable is simply an array that you can use as any other array in PHP.

Comment: Your `session_unset()` and `session_regenerate_id()` destroys/invalidates your current session values.

Comment: Btw. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your query.

Comment: ...and you're only checking the email, not the password, which means that anyone can login as any other user if they got their email.

Comment: ...and your `$loginsql` actually contains the result of the query, not the sql-string. You are trying to do another sql query on the next row using the results from the query above.

Comment: guys, I have edited my login.php. Can you guys take a look?

Comment: So, what happens now, then? The same error? Btw. You should read upon a bit on "password hashing". Now you have the password in clear text in your DB (that's how passwords ends up on the dark web).

Answer (score 0):

Some revised code from what the comments suggested:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("config.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN'])) {
  header("Location: index.php");
  die();
}

$useremail = $_POST['Lemail'];
$userpassword =  $_POST['Lpass'];
$loginres = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userEmail='$useremail'" );
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($loginres);
if($numrows == 1)
{

  $loginrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($loginres);
  $_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN'] = 1;
  $_SESSION['SESS_USEREMAIL'] = $loginrow['userEmail'];
  $_SESSION['SESS_USERPASS'] = $loginrow['userpassword'];
  $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']  = $loginrow['username'];
  header("Location: index.php");
  die();
}
else {
  header("Location: http://" .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . "?error=1");
  die();
}
```

A few other notes: leave off the closing `?>` if all you include in a file is PHP, that prevents output from bleeding into the buffer. In this code you never check the user's password - probably a good idea. Finally, there is never a good reason to store a user's password as a session variable.

Comment: There are so many other things wrong with this code that will totally fail. Look at the `$loginsql` and `$loginres`-rows. This needs to be totally rewritten. :)

Comment: true. not to mention using mysqli in the first place.

Comment: Well, Mysqli still works fine (assuming that he's going to stick with Mysql and not change database vendor), but he should use prepared statements. He should also validate the user with the password, not just the email :p

Comment: You're totally correct. I just gives me the heebie-jeebies to think about these kinds of unprepared and unescaped queries going out into the wild. Of course, I suppose someone could do that with `PDO::query()` too.

Comment: guys, I have edited my login.php. Can you guys take a look?

Comment: Have you actually tried running the code? There are syntax errors in your code and your SQL (in your updated code too).

Answer (score -2):

i don't approve you,can you to ajax or goto.

```js
$.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          async:false,
          url:"this.php",
          data:{url:"a"},
          beforeSend: function () {
            alertLoad('loding...');
          },
          success:function(GetRes){
               thisdom.html(GetRes);
          },
          error:function(){
               alertNew('error.');
          }         


  });
```

this.php
    `<?php
    echo $this_data;
    ?>`